# Combining two high-VP chemicals to get a low-VP mixture

Tags: vapor-pressure, mixtures

I'd like to do a class experiment as a metaphor for human relationships.  Two people each have a different chemical which evaporates quickly (at STP).  There is one glass between them.  If only one person pours his/her chemical into the glass, it quickly evaporates.  However, if both pour equal portions of their respective chemicals into the glass, it is a stable mixture which can fill the glass and not evaporate.

Are there two such chemicals that will do this?

Comment: I cannot immediately come up with an example for *evaporating* chemicals, but how about epoxy resin? It is usually sold as a two liquid components which quickly solidify upon mixing. As solid as friendship in a fairy tale.

Comment: Thanks.  Epoxy resin won't work for this analogy; because the idea is that, if one person doesn't add anything, the glass becomes empty fairly quickly.  I.E., the only way to fill the glass and keep it full is if both people are adding what they can.

Comment: Well, there's plenty of [azeotropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope) which are somewhat less volatile then their constituents.

Comment: Silane and oxygen, although the transition to a low vapor-pressure state is, well, exciting...

Comment: Both components need to be liquid at STP; therefore, the Silane/Oxygen combo doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Mithoron.  Can you suggest a good azeotrope with high vapor pressure constituents? -- something easily available?

Comment: With regard to common azeotropes, I've been through the entire list; and virtually every azeotrope has a lower bp than its constituents.  That's the opposite of what we need.